# Searching for an item by a known value of an element in the array of an element in the array

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a known value for an element, `ENTRYID` in my JSON Document. I want to get the `Tasks.Id` for the element of `Tasks` that has an `ENTRYID` matching my known value. The issue is that `ENTRYID` is a little bit buried inside `Tasks`. As an example, here is the JSON Path to find the first `ENTRYID` in the document.

```
$.Tasks[0].Activities[0].Entry.AnswersFlat[0].ENTRYID
```

For pathing to `ENTRYID` from a `Tasks` element, it is always in `Activities[0].Entry.AnswersFlat[0]`. Those two arrays do not need to be searched.

I know I can use `?(@.Tag == 'Known Value')` to find elements that contain a known value for a specific tag name but when I try to use that in my JSON path, I keep getting errors. I've tried:

```
$.Tasks[?(@.Activities[0].Entry.AnswersFlat[0].ENTRYID=='95B53C6CF6104F0E86B5744083A22FAD')].Id
```

But this returns an error.

I have also tried nesting the filters but that also returns an error :

```
$.Tasks[?(@.Activites[?(@.Entry.AnswersFlat[?(@.ENTRYID=='95B53C6CF6104F0E86B5744083A22FAD')])])].Id
```

**What is the correct syntax in JSON Path to get the** `Tasks.Id` **for my known value of** `ENTRYID`**?**

I have created a very simplified version of my document for your reference:

```json
{
   "Tasks":[
      {
         "Id":"652a187f2a584a0f84aaadb9016cfa4b",
         "Activities":[
            {
               "Entry":{
                  "AnswersFlat":[
                     {
                        "ENTRYID":"95B53C6CF6104F0E86B5744083A22FAD"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Id":"e586073810a746cca440adb901090326",
         "Activities":[
            {
               "Entry":{
                  "AnswersFlat":[
                     {
                        "ENTRYID":"7FD608F3F9E24EB084F58A1245677B3D"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I ended up switching the data output to XML instead of JSON and it was so easy to get what I wanted. `//Task[.//ENTRYID="95B53C6CF6104F0E86B5744083A22FAD"]/Id`

Comment: `$.Tasks[?(@.Activities[0].Entry.AnswersFlat[0].ENTRYID=='95B53C6CF6104F0E86B5744083A22FAD')].Id` gives the exact output in https://jsonpath.com/. Which implementation of jsonpath are you using and in which language?

Comment: @AkshayG I'm astounded, annoyed and amused that I already had the answer and couldn't make it work. Thank you.

Comment: @AkshayG I was on [this](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/#) website, default settings, and when I run the same lines it gives me an error... I'm never using that website again...